# Q : Power BI Dax calculation, Scenario Actual vs several weeks

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculation

I've got this dataset :

[image: Dataset example]

I need to display in a Matrix, Week 1 vs Actual, Week 2 vs Actual, Week 3 vs Actual ...

I've tried this calculation

```
Actual CA :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'All Scenario'[Amount] ),
    FILTER ( 'All Scenario', 'All Scenario'[scenario] = "ACTUAL" )
)

Weekly CA :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'All Scenario'[Amount] ),
    FILTER ( 'All Scenario', 'All Scenario'[scenario] = "WEEKLY" )
)


Variance := [Actual CA] - [Weekly CA]
```

But this is what I get when I put the measures in a Matrix :

[image: Matrix picture]

Answer (score 0):

You should remove filter context from "row"; in your FILTER, replace table name with ALL(TableName) or even ALL(TableName[ColumnToDropFilter]))